# Set a condition for elements with the same class in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a couple of checkboxes that I want to check if the user selected them,
If he selected 2, then he can't select more.
The problem is that I use the them several times in diffrent rows and they have the same class.

How can I check in javascript if only 2 checkboxes are selected in each group of buttons?

**HTML:**

```
<td> 
    <!-- First Group of Buttons -->
    <p>Barcelona</p>
    <label class="dir-bet" type="checkbox">Barcelona Win</label>
</td>
<td class="middle-table">
  <p>VS</p>
  <label class="dir-bet" type="checkbox">Draw</label>
</td>
<td class="team-header">
    <p>R.Madrid</p>
    <label class="dir-bet" type="checkbox">R.MadridWin</label>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> 
    <!-- Second Group of Buttons -->
    <p>Barcelona</p>
    <label class="dir-bet" type="checkbox">Barcelona Win</label>
</td>
<td class="middle-table">
  <p>VS</p>
  <label class="dir-bet" type="checkbox">Draw</label>
</td>
<td class="team-header">
    <p>R.Madrid</p>
    <label class="dir-bet" type="checkbox">R.Madrid Win</label>
</td>
```

**Java-Script:**

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("dir-bet");

var checkBet = function(){
var checkNum = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    if(list[i].getAttribute("checked")){
        checkNum++;
    }
  }
  if (checkNum<2 ) {
      if(this.getAttribute("checked")){
        this.setAttribute("checked","");
        this.classList.remove ("prime-bg", "prime-clr");
      }else{
        this.setAttribute("checked","true");
        this.classList.add ("prime-bg", "prime-clr");
      }
  }else{
    if(this.getAttribute("checked")){
        this.setAttribute("checked","");
        this.classList.remove ("prime-bg", "prime-clr");
    }
  }
};

for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
list[i].addEventListener("click", checkBet);
}
```

Comment: You could make your life easier by grouping the checkboxes with html or with name attribute first? From there it should be fairly easy ..

Comment: I thought about it, but if I have 20 lines with checkboxes i'll need to create 20 attributes. Is there a better way?

Comment: Do you hardcode all the data? You could probably use server side language to store them in an array (or get them from DB) and display them easily like that without any hassle. Also, attributes are no an issue since I was thinking of making one name for each group like so: name="groupname[]"

Comment: For now I'm only doing the client, so I wanted to find a solution in HTML/JS. If the easiest way is an attribute per row so be it :) I thought I'll find something less messy.

Comment: jQuery would make your life easier on this one I guess, is it not an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check in which table row your click happens, and then get only the list of `dir-bet` class elements that are within that row. Then apply your counting logic on that smaller list of elements.

With some other improvements, your `checkBet` function could look like this:

```
var checkBet = function () {
    var checked = this.getAttribute("checked");
    if (!checked) { // a count is only needed when adding a check mark:
        var list = this.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("dir-bet");
        var checkNum = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (list[i].getAttribute("checked")) {
                checkNum++;
            }
        }

        if (checkNum >= 2) return; // reject
    }

    // toggle the check status
    checked = !checked;
    this.setAttribute("checked", checked ? "true" : "");
    this.classList.toggle("prime-bg", checked);
    this.classList.toggle("prime-clr", checked);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If jQuery is an option, here's a solution :

```js
let $checkboxes = $("input[type=checkbox]")
 
$checkboxes.click(() => {
  $checkboxes.attr("disabled", false)
  if ($("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length == 2) {
    $("input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)").attr("disabled", true)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Can check only 2 checkboxes</h2>
<br/>
<input type="checkbox"/><span>Checkbox 1</span><br/>
<input type="checkbox"/><span>Checkbox 2</span><br/>
<input type="checkbox"/><span>Checkbox 3</span><br/>
<input type="checkbox"/><span>Checkbox 4</span><br/>
<input type="checkbox"/><span>Checkbox 5</span><br/>
<input type="checkbox"/><span>Checkbox 6</span><br/>
<input type="checkbox"/><span>Checkbox 7</span><br/>
<input type="checkbox"/><span>Checkbox 8</span><br/>
<input type="checkbox"/><span>Checkbox 9</span><br/>
<input type="checkbox"/><span>Checkbox 10</span><br/>
```